# How to find the nearest location points?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that has customer_number, customer_location(lat, long), current_latched_tower_ID, tower_location(lat,long) and Distance(between cx location and latched tower location). I am trying to find a tower that is very closer to the customer location rather than current_latched_tower.

Example: One customer currently latched to one tower(KA001), the distance between customer location and latched tower location is 1.6KM. However, there is another tower(KA002) very closer to the customer location. Thus, its distance between customer location and closest tower location is 1.3KM.

Table

```
customer_number   cx_lat       cx_long      tower_lat   tower_long  Latched_tower_ID   Distance
34532             6.897257333  79.86474533  6.890487    79.869199   CM0321             0.51477
43445             6.935598403  81.14939421  6.947618    81.160246   BD0010             1.2292
54365             6.866224     79.88215     6.896111    79.868611   CM0037             1.6216
52568             7.113198     80.037247    7.121666    80.028888   GM0121             0.9476
```

Expecting output table

```
customer_number   cx_lat       cx_long      tower_lat   tower_long  Latched_tower_ID   Distance  Cloesed_tower_ID  Closed_Distance
34532             6.897257333  79.86474533  6.890487    79.869199   CM0321             0.51477   CM0037            0.43222
52568             7.113198     80.037247    7.121666    80.028888   GM0121             0.9476  NULL                NULL
```

if don't have any closer tower rather than latched tower "Cloesed_tower_ID" and "Closed_Distance" columns should be NULL

Comment: do you have `sdo_geom` installed ? I mean, the distance is calculated in application side or in the database

Comment: Does it need to be accurate? If not, then Pythagoras equation would be a first approximation (if you only the the shortest distance but not the actual value) for small distances. Otherwise have a look at haversine formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using `SDO_GEOM` then you can create the haversine function to calculate the distance between two latitude/longditude co-ordinates:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION haversine_distance(
  lat1  IN NUMBER,
  long1 IN NUMBER,
  lat2  IN NUMBER,
  long2 IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  PI           CONSTANT NUMBER := ASIN(1) * 2;
  R            CONSTANT NUMBER := 6371000; -- Approx. radius of the earth in m
  PHI1         CONSTANT NUMBER := lat1 * PI / 180;
  PHI2         CONSTANT NUMBER := lat2 * PI / 180;
  DELTA_PHI    CONSTANT NUMBER := (lat2 - lat1) * PI / 180;
  DELTA_LAMBDA CONSTANT NUMBER := (long2 - long1) * PI / 180;
  a NUMBER;
  c NUMBER;
BEGIN
  a := SIN(delta_phi/2) * SIN(delta_phi/2) + COS(phi1) * COS(phi2) *
          SIN(delta_lambda/2) * SIN(delta_lambda/2);
  c := 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1-a));
  RETURN R * c; -- in metres
END;
/
```

Then, I am assuming that you have your data in third normal form:

```sql
CREATE TABLE towers (
  tower_id PRIMARY KEY,
  t_lat,
  t_long
) AS
SELECT 'CM0321', 6.890487, 79.869199 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BD0010', 6.947618, 81.160246 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CM0037', 6.896111, 79.868611 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GM0121', 7.121666, 80.028888 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE customers (
  customer_number PRIMARY KEY,
  cx_lat,
  cx_long,
  latched_tower_id
) AS
SELECT 34532, 6.897257333, 79.86474533, 'CM0321' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43445, 6.935598403, 81.14939421, 'BD0010' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 54365, 6.866224000, 79.88215000, 'CM0037' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 52568, 7.113198000, 80.03724700, 'GM0121' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE customers ADD CONSTRAINT customers__lti__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (latched_tower_id) REFERENCES towers (tower_id);
```

Then, from Oracle 12, you can calculate the closer towers using:

```sql
SELECT c.*,
       TO_CHAR(
         HAVERSINE_DISTANCE(c.cx_lat, c.cx_long, t.t_lat, t.t_long)/1000,
         'FM999990.000'
       ) AS distance,
       ct.tower_id AS closer_tower_id,
       TO_CHAR(ct.distance, 'FM999990.000') AS closer_distance
FROM   customers c
       INNER JOIN towers t
       ON (t.tower_id = c.latched_tower_id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT ct.*,
                HAVERSINE_DISTANCE(
                    c.cx_lat,
                    c.cx_long,
                    ct.t_lat,
                    ct.t_long
                )/1000 AS distance
         FROM   towers ct
         ORDER BY distance ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) ct
       ON (ct.tower_id != c.latched_tower_id);
```

Which outputs:

> | CUSTOMER_NUMBER | CX_LAT | CX_LONG | LATCHED_TOWER_ID | DISTANCE | CLOSER_TOWER_ID | CLOSER_DISTANCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 43445 | 6.935598403 | 81.14939421 | BD0010 | 1.795 |  |  |
> | 54365 | 6.866224 | 79.88215 | CM0037 | 3.644 | CM0321 | 3.053 |
> | 34532 | 6.897257333 | 79.86474533 | CM0321 | 0.899 | CM0037 | 0.445 |
> | 52568 | 7.113198 | 80.037247 | GM0121 | 1.318 |  |  |

---

Before Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT customer_number,
       cx_lat,
       cx_long,
       latched_tower_id,
       distance,
       CASE
       WHEN latched_tower_id != closer_tower_id
       THEN closer_tower_id
       END AS closer_tower_id,
       CASE
       WHEN latched_tower_id != closer_tower_id
       THEN closer_distance
       END AS closer_distance
FROM   (
  SELECT c.*,
         TO_CHAR(
           HAVERSINE_DISTANCE(c.cx_lat, c.cx_long, t.t_lat, t.t_long)/1000,
           'FM999990.000'
         ) AS distance,
         ct.tower_id AS closer_tower_id,
         TO_CHAR(
           HAVERSINE_DISTANCE(c.cx_lat, c.cx_long, ct.t_lat, ct.t_long)/1000,
           'FM999990.000'
         ) AS closer_distance,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY c.customer_number
           ORDER BY HAVERSINE_DISTANCE(c.cx_lat, c.cx_long, ct.t_lat, ct.t_long)
         ) AS rn
  FROM   customers c
         INNER JOIN towers t
         ON (t.tower_id = c.latched_tower_id)
         CROSS JOIN towers ct
  ORDER BY
         customer_number,
         DISTANCE ASC
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5dc140558ae49190b5a3dd799d9ed6f)*

Comment: Hi @MT0 , i have already these two tables in my data base schema(customer, tower). how to like those tables using FOREIGN KEY?

Comment: @ChulaxshanGunasegaram Sorry, I cannot understand your question. What does it mean to "like" those tables?

Comment: "ALTER TABLE customers ADD CONSTRAINT customers__lti__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (latched_tower_id) REFERENCES towers (tower_id); " this code not working for me, because customer and tower table already created by DB admin. i have only select privilege. So, how can make relationship between these two tables?

Comment: @ChulaxshanGunasegaram You do not need to add the constraint if the tables already exist; you just need to use the `SELECT` query.